# Android camera changes dimensions when rotating phone

Tags: android, camera, orientation, surfaceview

I'm developing an android application which uses the camera. I got a problem with surfaceChanged() method. Here is my code.

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

    if (mPreviewRunning) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

    parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mCamera.startPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = true;
}
```

the variable mPreviewRunning is initialized as false at the beginning. program runs just fine with horizontal orientation. but when I rotates the phone to the vertical orientation the screen is rotated and is stretched. I can't understand why it's happened. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I solved this problem by fixing the orientation of activity to **landscape** in manifest file. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camera does not change  orientation at all - CCD is soldered  to motherboard , and delivers pixels as if it were in landscape mode ( most probably )  however,   your activity  could be restarted by OS on orientation change, unless you disable it in manifest.

( and your surface view is recreated on this restart )

Look in this project for android demos  handling camera management:

https://sourceforge.net/p/javaocr/source/ci/5cb9b4176f40ada57296cce79addd205e4c1405c/tree/demos/camera-utils/src/main/java/net/sf/javaocr/demos/android/utils/camera/CameraManager.java#l85

Your mistake is  to set preview size from surface size - do not do this.  Camera provides limited set of acceptable preview sizes and is free to ignore other settings ( exact behaviour is device depending)

Preview size means used CCD resolution,   and camera software will render  it on your surface view in size of the surface view doung scaling as necessary.